# Questão de Fibonacci em Java

Tags: java, algoritmo

Eu tenho uma questão e a resolução dela, que precisa ser com `while` ou `do-while`. Mas não entendi a resolução, alguém poderia me explicar? Vou comentar a dúvida específica de cada linha.

> A Sequência de Fibonacci é uma sequência de números inteiros na qual,
>   cada termo subsequente corresponde a soma dos dois anteriores. Sendo
>   assim, elabore um *algoritmo* que informe uma sequencia de Fibonacci que
>   liste os valores iniciados com 0 até o valor 2584.

Resolução:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x1=0;

    int x2=1;  // Por que tem que declarar duas variáveis?

    do{         System.out.print(x1 + " " );  // Por que o "  " depois do x1?

         x2= x2 +x1;   // Também não entendi por quê isso

         x1= x2-x1;    // Nem isso

    }while(x1<2584);}}  // E por que tem que ser do-while.
```

Comment: Infelizmente nem todo programador liga para o nome que dá as variáveis, campos, classes e tudo que se pode dar nome. Isso **dificulta mais ainda a leitura do código**. Muitas vezes `x`, `x1`, `a`, `b`, `aux` são péssimas escolhas. Isso é melhor abordado no livro [Clean Code](https://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882), que considero uma leitura **indispensável** para qualquer desenvolvedor hoje em dia.

Comment: @vnbrs ótima sugestão de leitura. A tradução em pt-br tem algumas gafes mas nada que comprometa seriamente a qualidade do conteúdo nem da leitura

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade acho que precisa de um curso com o básico de lógica e algoritmo antes de tentar entender isso.

Refiz o código porque ele está bem errado. Coloquei nomes melhores nas variáveis que ajuda entender

```
class Fibonacci {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int termo1 = 0;
        int termo2 = 1; //se são dois termos, precisa de duas várias para controlar
        do {
            System.out.print(termo1 + " "); //Está mandando imprimir um dos termos
            int temp = termo1 + termo2; //somando os dois últimos termos conforme o enunciado
            termo1 = termo2;  //fazendo o primeiro termo ter o valor do segundo
            termo2 = temp; //fazendo o segundo termo ter o valor somado dos últimos termos
        } while (termo1 <= 2584); //precisa de um laço para ficar repetindo até a condição
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ixsYmW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rsmcqigc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/FibonacciExplain.java).

> "A Sequência de Fibonacci é uma sequência de números inteiros na qual, cada termo subsequente corresponde a soma dos dois anteriores. Sendo assim, elabore um algoritmo que informe uma sequencia de Fibonacci que liste os valores iniciados com 0 até o valor 2584.
>
> A Sequência de Fibonacci é uma sequência de números inteiros

Se é uma sequência precisamos de uma estrutura de controle de fluxo que fique repetindo cada elemento da sequência. E se é número inteiro precisamos de ao menos algum dado inteiro, provavelmente estará em variável.

> cada termo subsequente corresponde a soma dos dois anteriores

Já sabemos como obter os termos subsequentes. Se precisa sempre somar os dois anteriores precisamos iniciar com dois deles, daí temos pelo menos duas variáveis.

> valores iniciados com 0 até o valor 2584

Então o termo inicial é 0 e por definição de Fibonacci o segundo é 1.

Sabemos também que a repetição deve continuar até que se atinja o termo 2584 por isso essa é a condição que deve ser verdadeira para o laço de repetição continuar com o fluxo dentro dele. Uma das formas que tem para fazer isto é o `do-while` onde a primeira vez sempre será executado o blocos de comandos e depois da primeira iteração ele decide se continua ou não. Tem como fazer de outras formas. Note que a condição estava errada, ela desconsiderava o último número. O enunciado me passa a ideia que ele deve ser incluído.

Obviamente que cada vez que repetimos um termo precisamos imprimir, por isso precisamos chamar a função que faz a impressão. Seria interessante dar um espaço entre os termos impressos.

Novamente voltamos à explicação de como obter o novo termo e é a soma dos dois últimos termos, então criamos uma variável para guardar essa soma. Neste momento temos 3 termos, e só precisamos de 2. De fato podemos dizer que agora o primeiro termo passa ter o valor do segundo, e em seguida podemos dizer que o segundo tem o valor do terceiro que acabou de ser gerado, logo em seguida não precisamos mais de um terceiro valor. Isso é necessário para manter o padrão de operação do laço de repetição, sempre vai somar o 1o. e 2o. termos.

Aí se repetir imprime o novo primeiro termo e começa calcular tudo de novo.

Alguém poderia questionar se precisa da variável temporária para calcular o termo subsequente. E precisa.

Se já jogasse a soma dos dois termos no segundo, você não teria mais o valor anterior do segundo termo para jogar no primeiro termo.

Se copiasse o segundo termo para o primeiro antes, aí a soma sairia errada porque na prática estaria somando o segundo termo com o primeiro que já tem o valor do segundo, já teria perdido o valor do primeiro. No fundo estaria dobrando o valor e não fazendo Fibonacci que é sempre ir somando a a sequência.

Com *array* dá para simplificar um pouco porque na prática passa ter várias variáveis, você não perde os termos anteriores nunca.

Comment: [@meta] Não sei se vale responder uma pergunta do tipo "Me descreva linha a linha o que eu fiz, porque eu não sei visualizar o algoritmo."
A ideia é implementação de como matar problemas reais, não cobrir o exercício de faculdade.

Comment: Nossa, obrigada pela resposta tão dedicada! Na verdade minhas dúvidas são realmente sobre a lógica, porque essa questão é da matéria de Lógica de programação que estou pegando na faculdade, no 1 semestre. O professor indicou este site para quando tivéssemos dúvidas, mas pelo o que estou vendo, perguntas de lógica não são muito bem-vindas por aqui. De qualquer forma, obrigada pela explicação, Maniero.

Comment: @SparK ideia de quem? A pergunta não estava na sua melhor forma, mas ela é totalmente pertinente ao site.

Comment: @Maniero `fn = fn−1 + fn−2`. A dúvida não foi a lógica, foi a regra de negócio. Bom, podemos remover a tag Java.